# How to manage AndroidMenifest xml in Android

Tags: java, android

I have Activity 'A' , 'B' , 'C', 'D', 'E' .The main activity is 'A', as defined in the AndroidManifest XML file, is started when the application is started. After that i have to call another activity 'B' then 'C' ,'D' And after 'D' i have to call 'E'.But when i start my app always start the main Activity 'A'.But I,m trying to call only once Activity 'A'  when start the app first time and after that when i start the app second time i want to call Activity 'B'.How to manage this in Android.

Here is my AndroidMenifest xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sqlitedemo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.sqlitedemo.A"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" 
                  />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity android:name="com.sqlitedemo.B"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.sqlitedemo.C"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.sqlitedemo.D"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.sqlitedemo.E"></activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Use SharedPreference. Store some value when you go to Activity A. When you launch again at that time check whether value is present in SP or not. If it is present then go to B.

Comment: Too many answers related to this question. You need to search them instead of creating one new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need to update your manifest file. Just redirect to class B from class A, for this you need to use SharedPreference.

```
public class A extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
    SharedPreferences settings=getSharedPreferences("prefs",0);
    boolean firstRun=settings.getBoolean("firstRun",false);
    if(firstRun==false)//if running for first time
      {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=settings.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("firstRun",true);
        editor.commit();
       //execute your code for first time
    }
    else
    {
        Intent a=new Intent(A.this,B.class); 
        startActivity(a);
        finish();
    }
   }

}
```

Comment: Was in the process of writing :P +1 :)

Comment: Yes, you can manage that from the launcher activity and preferences. If you are using activities, you can set the first activity as a Splash screen so that you can make a check there an redirect to the desired activity after a delay of few 100 milli seconds.

You may also consider using fragments for the same so that you can inflate the required fragment after condition checks.

Comment: @Prince : It works for my app , thanks a lot millions .

Comment: Glad to help you, Happy codding :)

Comment: Somewhere I have read it to initialise SP like this `SharedPreferences settings = this.getSharedPreferences("prefs",0);`

Comment: getSharedPreferences() is a Context method. If a class that extends Context, such as Activity, you don't have to do context.getSharedPreferences()

Answer (score 0):

Well this you would have to solve using your own logic. What you can do is have a myfile.txt and use it to save a flag(or use a properties file with flag default=1). When the app opens for the first time open App A and  set flag to 2. The next time app opens up it reads Flag=2 so open App B and set flag to 3 etc etc.
You'll have App A launched always anyways, but you can prevent complete initialisation of the app by not calling super.onCreate(xxx) of App A.

Write the app opening business logic before calling super.onCreate for App A.

**In short you would have to handle the APP opening manually.**

Comment: This is one way of doing it.